# Cycle through values in a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to find a solution for this problem, I have two tables

Table no 1

```
| no | ticket |
|----|--------|
| 1  | T1     |
| 2  | T2     |
| 3  | T3     |
```

Table no 2

```
| id | CustomerId |
|----|------------|
| 1  | C1         |
| 2  | C2         |
```

I require a below set

```
| Tickeid | CustomerId |
|---------|------------|
| T1      | C1         |
| T2      | C2         |
| T3      | C1         |
```

It basically cycle with ticketid , I started with a cross join on both table but couldn't get the required result

**EDIT:1**
One change that can happen is the values in table 2 can have more than 2 values
like in table 1 have T1,T2,T3,T4 and table 2 have C1,C2,C3 then I require
T1C1,T2C2,T3C3,T4C1

Again

if table 2 is just C1

then I just Need T1C1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the recent changes to your question, I've completely rewritten my answer.  There may be more efficient ways of doing this, but here's my solution.  Let me know if I have misunderstood your request.

```
--set up demo data
declare @Table1 table (no int, ticket varchar(5))
insert into @Table1 (no, ticket) values
(1,'T1'),(2,'T2'),(3,'T3'),(4,'T4'),(5,'T5'),(6,'T6'),(7,'T7'),(8,'T8'),(9,'T9'),(10,'T10'),(11,'T11')

declare @Table2 table (ID int, CustomerId varchar(5))
insert into @Table2 (id, CustomerId) values(1,'C1'),(2,'C2'),(3,'C3'),(4,'C4')

--The actual solution
;
--Table2 row count
WITH Table2RowCount 
AS (
    SELECT count(*) AS T2RowCount
    FROM @Table2
    )
--Add row number (sequence) to Table1 rows
    ,Table1AndRowNumber 
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() OVER (
            ORDER BY no
            ) AS sequence
    FROM @Table1
    )
--Add row number (sequence) to Table2 rows
    ,Table2AndRowNumber 
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() OVER (
            ORDER BY id
            ) AS sequence
    FROM @Table2
    )
--Add a grouping column for Table1 using the modulus operator
--This grp column will be used to join up against the sequence column of Table2
    ,Table1Grouped      
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,CASE 
            WHEN t1arn.sequence % (t2rc.T2RowCount) = 0
                THEN (t2rc.T2RowCount)
            ELSE t1arn.sequence % (t2rc.T2RowCount)
            END AS grp
    FROM Table1AndRowNumber t1arn
    CROSS APPLY Table2RowCount t2rc
    )
SELECT t1g.ticket
    ,t2arn.CustomerId
FROM Table1Grouped t1g
JOIN Table2AndRowNumber t2arn ON t2arn.sequence = t1g.grp
```

---

```
| ticket | CustomerId |
|--------|------------|
| T1     | C1         |
| T2     | C2         |
| T3     | C3         |
| T4     | C4         |
| T5     | C1         |
| T6     | C2         |
| T7     | C3         |
| T8     | C4         |
| T9     | C1         |
| T10    | C2         |
| T11    | C3         |
```

Comment: hoddgin, the solution is right as per the question but there is a slight change, table 2 can have more values so, if table 1 have t1,t2,t3,t4 and table 2 has c1,c2,c3 then I need t1c1,t2c2,t3c3,t4c1, the same way if table 1 has t1  and table 2 has c1,c2,c3 i just need t1,c1

Comment: hoddgin, I am editing the question as per the change.

Comment: @Bijujose - based on the changes in your question, I’ve rewritten my answer

Comment: yup this is the one,  I did some test for checking the results and its fine.

Answer (score 2):

Number arithmetic you need indeed (and the modulus operator).

The following takes care of gaps in the `id` and `no` values as well. The `ROW_NUMBER()` provides gapless numbers and the `-1` makes the numbers start from `0` (we need that because the `% n` operator gives results from `0` up to `n - 1`):

```
with t as
  ( select ticketid = ticket,
           rn = row_number() over (order by no) - 1
    from tickets
  ),
c as
  ( select customerid,
           rn = row_number() over (order by id) - 1,
           total_count = count(*) over ()
    from customers
  )  
select t.ticketid,
       c.customerid
from t join c 
     on t.rn % c.total_count = c.rn ;
```